# When one check is selected all other checkbox in a form must get disabled - Not Working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a form with multiple check box. Now when i click on one of the check box, the other should get disabled. 
My JavaScript code part is not working i.e. one one check box is selected, all other check box doesn't get disabled

```
<tr> <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '79'>Q- 79. Currency of japan </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '80'>Q- 80. Statute of Liberty is in ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '64'>Q- 64. National Animal ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '65'>Q- 65. Popular language </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '63'>Q- 63. Largest Ocean ? </td> </tr>
```

JS:

```
function isUncheck(){

        for (i=0; i<document.myForm.check1.length; i++){
        if (document.myForm.check1[i].checked !=true)
        document.myForm.check1[i].disabled='true';
}
```

My Function call:

```
<tr><td> <input type="submit" name="edit" style="height: 20px;width: 250px" formmethod='post' formaction='/~xyz/cgi-bin/Project/CheckEdit.py' value="Edit" onclick="return(isUncheck())"></td></tr><br>
```

Comment: Just use radio buttons.

Comment: I want to work with checkbox only. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4XSU/

```
onclick="isUncheck();"

function isUncheck(){
  var checkboxes=document.getElementsByName("check1");
   for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
    if (!checkboxes[i].checked)   checkboxes[i].disabled='true';
   }
}
```

Comment: When user deselect the checkbox, it should enable all then too

Comment: @user3003685, well for that OP has to specify whether enabling is needed or not!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to burn in hell for this. UX wise you should be using radio buttons.
But, since you insist on using checkboxes, [**here's the solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/9Sa85/).

```
function updateOthers(target){
     var chk = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     for(var i=0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        if(chk[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if(chk[i] != target) {
                chk[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
     }
   }
```